# When are you allowed to play monster boosters in Munchkin Quest?

Tags: munchkin-quest

Several cards beef up monsters (such as "...with Eyes In the Back of Its Head").  These cards do not say "Play at any time" on them, so according to my reading of the rules they should only be playable during your own turn, but people I've played with claim you can play them when a opponent is facing a monster.

What's correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Pat I think, but it was a different section of the rules that caught my eye:

> Certain cards, called monster
>   enhancers, raise or lower the combat
>   strength of individual monsters. (Yes,
>   you can have a negative enhancement.)
>   **Monster enhancers may be played by any
>   player during any combat.**

I don't know if we're looking at the same version of the rules or different ones, but the general facts of the case seem clear!

Comment: same section.  The part you quoted is the start of the paragraph.  Mine is the end of it :)

Comment: remember though that potions and scrolls can only be used if you are in the same room or in an adjacent room.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the side bar entitled, "Non-Helpers in Combat" on [page 10 of the rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/munchkinquest/munchkinquest_rules.pdf) for the explanation of when you can play monster boosters.

> Play a Monster Enhancer on one of the monsters in the
>   fight
>
> ...
>
> **You can play these at any time, not just during combat**